# When is javascript code considered garbage for the GC

Tags: javascript, memory

So i've been getting into the more advanced parts of javascript. Right now im learning about memory, memory leaks and garbage collecting. Many examples on the web just exaplain what the garbage collector is , but i am having trouble finding one that tells me when the code is considered garbage for the garbage collector.

So far I've read "When there's no longer a reference pointing to an object". Is that the only case? What exactly do they mean by that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to see it as code being reachable or not from the roots, and roots are values that are inherently always reachable, such as global variables. The garbage collector in JS uses a "mark and sweep" algorithm, where it starts from the roots and visits each reference and their references and so on. Once it's visited, it gets marked as being visited/reachable together with all reachable references from there, and will not be visited again.

You can have references pointing to objects, which maybe also have references to other objects, but once they can never be reached anymore from the root, they form a sort of unreachable island of references. They will never get visited and will finally be sweeped away by the garbage collector.

There are also several optimizations done. For example some objects get created and do their job once and then die off. Those new ones get cleaned up very aggressively and fast. If they are used for longer periods of time they will be considered old, and will be visited less often to check if they should be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly they mean by that:

Garbage Collection has two basic algorithms called **mark and sweep algorithm**. So what's going to happen in the algorithm is the garbage collector sort of can say what memory is still accessible. Mark works out what's live, sweep gets rid of the stuff that isn't. So that's the straightforward version. Sweep where anything that's not marked.

Is that the only case? The answer is no.

Garbage Collection triggers when the heap size gets bigger than the limitation. How do I know? I cloned the V8 engine and used d8 shells to check garbage collection and there was no garbage collection even though there's no longer a reference pointing to an object (if you force `gc()` you could see garbage collection). So just a few lines won't trigger GC even though there's no longer a reference pointing to an object.